# How to debug segmentation faults in large problems?

Tags: parallel-computing, fortran, scalapack

I am sorry if this question seems like off topic or opinion based, but I was not sure how to go about it.

I am currently working on a 100k x 100k positive definite linear system and trying to solve it using Cholesky factorization from Scalapack 2.1.0 (`pdpotrf`). My problem is that when I run the same system for 50kx50k matrix (i.e. A(1:50000,1:50000)) my program runs fine. However it is giving segmentation fault in 100k run:

```
Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7f8126942b9a in ???
#1  0x7f8126941dc3 in ???
#2  0x7f8125e4824f in ???
#3  0x45409d in ???
#4  0x44382c in pdpotf2_
        at /home/user/sclpk_solver/scalapack-2.1.0/SRC/pdpotf2.f:250
#5  0x414502 in pdpotrf_
        at /home/user/sclpk_solver/scalapack-2.1.0/SRC/pdpotrf.f:262
```

Normally I would like to use record-replay or such debugging tools to go about it, but given the size of the problem and the fact that it takes it about 10 hours before I get the failure, I am not sure how to even start debugging it. The exact same code and exact same data works fine on intel MKL(ver 2018 service pack 3). But GNU compilers are giving issue (version 4.8 and 7.1).

Any comments are welcome.

UPDATE: I just figured out an important detail: my program works for cores greater then 4. its <=4 when it gives the segmentation fault. I think its because for 100k, 4 or less cores mean each core will have > 50k*50k elements. so there is somewhere integer overflow error. It can be strengthened by the fact that when compiled with intel MKL, it needs -i8 flag for numroc function to work properly.

Also I tried compiling scalapack with "-g -Og" flag, and this time program failed with following output:

```
{*****,    0}:  On entry to PDPOTRF parameter number    1 had an illegal value
<< Warning >> pdpotrf FAILED      -1
{*****,    0}:  On entry to PDPOTRF parameter number    1 had an illegal value
<< Warning >> pdpotrf FAILED      -1
{    0,    0}:  On entry to PDPOTRS parameter number    1 had an illegal value
<< Warning >> pdpotrs FAILED
��������
 Solved! predicting test values
{    1,    0}:  On entry to PDPOTRS parameter number    1 had an illegal value
<< Warning >> pdpotrs FAILED
��������
 TIme for solving (sec)   9.0224840000000008E-003
{    0,    0}:  On entry to PDPOTRS parameter number    1 had an illegal value
<< Warning >> pdpotrs FAILED
��������
 Solved! delta test values
 TIme for solving (sec)   9.1293109999999993E-003
{    1,    0}:  On entry to PDPOTRS parameter number    1 had an illegal value
<< Warning >> pdpotrs FAILED
��������
~

PBLAS ERROR 'Illegal DESCA[INB_] = 0, DESCA[INB_] must be at least 1'
from {0,0}, pnum=0, Contxt=0, in routine 'PDGEMV'.

PBLAS ERROR 'Illegal DESCA[NB_] = 0, DESCA[NB_] must be at least 1'
from {0,0}, pnum=0, Contxt=0, in routine 'PDGEMV'.

PBLAS ERROR 'Illegal DESCA[RSRC_] = 100000, DESCA[RSRC_] must be either -1, or >= 0 and < 2'
from {0,0}, pnum=0, Contxt=0, in routine 'PDGEMV'.

PBLAS ERROR 'Illegal DESCA[M_] = 0, it must be at least 1'
from {0,0}, pnum=0, Contxt=0, in routine 'PDGEMV'.

PBLAS ERROR 'Illegal DESCX[INB_] = 0, DESCX[INB_] must be at least 1'
from {0,0}, pnum=0, Contxt=0, in routine 'PDGEMV'.
...
```

Any suggestions now?

Comment: It sounds like you are running out of memory due to fill in. I can not now as the backtrace is obfuscated due to optimization and lack of debug symbols. How many processes are you using and what is the amount of memory per process?

Comment: For the love of all that's numerically stable, please tell me you're not storing a sparse matrix in dense format? Secondly, you're using Scalapack which is a distributed memory solver. Do you actually have a cluster? Otherwise use a single-processor solver. And if you're running this on a single machine, you may very well run out of memory since 100k squared is about a Terabyte. Did you buy $50k worth of memory?

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Actually 8*(10^5)^2 bytes is 75 GiB. It sounds plausible that OP has 19 GiB available for the 50kx50k problem but not 75 GiB.

Comment: The backtrace isn't helpful because the libraries you're using weren't compiled with debugging symbols.  The first thing to do would be to rebuild the libraries with debugging symbols so that you can get a readable backtrace.

Comment: An out of memory error shouldn't show up as a segmentation fault.  A segmentation fault is something that you should bring up with the authors of the SCALAPACK library.

Comment: Well... Yes. We do have 1TB memory so its not running out of memory. No it's a dense Matrix only which couldn't have been sparsified. I have messaged in scalapack forum but even after two days they haven't posted the question :( it's running on 4 cores. But even single core I ran and same error

Comment: If you're running on 4 cores,you might as well try the LAPACK routine DPOTRF. Another thing to check, is the array you pass in to the cholesky routine properly allocated? Maybe you're allocating enough space for the 50k matrix but not the 100k?

Comment: @BrianBorchers, we don't know the amount of optimization done in compiling. There are multiple cases where an out-of-memory error may appear as a segmentation-fault due to compiler optimizations. A case -which is not applicable to this one- is when compiler allocates memory on heap rather than stack. But with 1TB memory, nothing of the sort is a problem.

Comment: The fact that you need -i8 to make the code works tells you that some library routine is expecting 8 byte long integers instead of conventional 32 bit integers.  With gfortran, the option -fdefault-integer-8 seems to be equivalent to ifort with -i8.

Comment: _Always_ compile with `-g`. It doesn't slow down the code, but improves your life when trying to figure things out. You could also try compiling with `-g -O3 -faddress=sanitize` - that'll tell you if you've misallocated memory or are accessing memory you shouldn't be at the cost of running at 1/2 speed. Still, you can start that running while you wait for better insight.

Answer (score 1):

There were some hints above already that this may be an integer range problem.  A 32 bit signed integer goes up to values of about 2e9.  A 50k x 50k symmetric matrix lives in an array of size about 5e4 * 5e4 / 2, which just about fits into an int32.  The 100k matrix will no longer be accessed correctly with 32 bit integers.

So you may need to go through your program and its interfaces to the solver libraries carefully and see which integers may need to be changed to 64 bit types, possibly using typedefs of unmistakable names to avoid mixups.

The other paradigm would be to make the choice that process-local indices should be 32 bit always and to access bigger data sets only through parallelization.